# Git filter-repo with --invert-paths flag doesn't work

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

I try to remove files from git history.

I am using **git filter-repo** whose github repository is https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo, but have some troubles.

As the example says here,
[https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES\](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES%5C)
and
https://marcofranssen.nl/remove-files-from-git-history-using-git-filter-repo/

I have tried these commands to remove .pyc files with `--force` flag:

```
sudo git filter-repo --path-glob '*/*.pyc' --invert-paths
sudo git filter-repo --path-glob '*.pyc' --invert-paths
sudo git filter-repo --path *.pyc --invert-paths
```

but nothing has effect.

The output of the command seems good but when I check the .pyc files, they all still exists.

Output:

```
Parsed 28 commits
New history written in 0.46 seconds; now repacking/cleaning... 
Repacking your repo and cleaning out old unneeded objects
HEAD is now at 1bc0b68 Re-add templates directory
Enumerating objects: 1084, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1084/1084), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (267/267), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1084/1084), done.
Total 1084 (delta 784), reused 1084 (delta 784), pack-reused 0
Completely finished after 1.33 seconds.
```

As it seems everything looks like going well but the files are not removed on git. The files are perfectly preserved and nothing becomes different.

Anybody knows the problem?

Comment: Not meant as an answer, but: (1) Don't run this under `sudo`. Make the repository owned by yourself and run it as yourself. (This should have no effect *here* but, just in general, never run anything with sudo unless absolutely necessary.) (2) Are you sure the rewritten *repository* has `*.pyc` files? The path-glob filter with `*.pyc` looks right to me. Note that if you're looking in the *working tree*, that's the wrong place to look.

Comment: @torek Thank you for your advice (1). And for (2), yes I checked several times the repository, files, and the branch. Everything is correct. If I'm not wrong, I think you also helped me on my last question. Thanks again for your kind advices.

Comment: you are strongly advised to not run using `--force`. Clone first, maybe to a bare repository `git clone --bare . ../repo-name.git`. The subsequent `--force` arguments are superflous. If you run `--force` once you shouldn't be warned again. Please consider removing the flag from your question and just state that you ran with the `--force` flag. People copy commands willy-nilly

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was putting the wrong path. I used "C:\RepoDir\DirectoryToBeRemoved" (note the backslashes), but should have used just "DirectoryToBeRemoved/"

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the reason but the problem is resolved. But still don't know why it happens.

When I try the commands above, everything seems go well but the files were not removed.

They were not removed from working tree, and even there was no change on commits or index(stage).
It means when I try

```
git diff
git diff HEAD
git diff --cached HEAD
```

No change was detected.

But when I push the branch and clone it in other directory again,
the *.pyc files seems to be removed.

I don't know the reason but it seems commit histories had been changed but it doesn't effect to local working tree and `git diff` didn't catch the changes.

I will check it more and update this answer if I find something.

---

Addition: also `git status` didn't show the *.pyc files as *not tracking* or *modified*.

---

I might find the point.
It was a stupid question.

`git status` and `git add` didn't show anything because of the `.gitignore`. Thanks and sorry to all who spent his/her time for this problem.

I will not remove this question even though it was a stupid question for whom who might do the same mistake with me.

Comment: Or I tried ```git filter-branch``` before ```git filter-repo```.
It could be crashed because of this.

Comment: It would be interesting (to the author of filter-repo, I think, too) if running filter-branch first leaves some sort of trap that makes filter-repo fail. If that's the case, there's probably some small, artificial repository you can create that would reproduce the effect.

Comment: @torek I think I find the point. Sorry it was a stupid one. And thanks again for your several helps. I could resolve it with your advices.

Comment: I think the issue you're encountering is that `git filter-repo` rewrites the index but doesn't update the working tree. If you did `git checkout HEAD`  or something you'd probably see the changes. You can also confirm files are deleted by running `git ls-files`, but this only applies if your files weren't deleted in `HEAD` before. Typically, you wouldn't run `git filter-repo` in a normal working repo. It usually makes more sense to do it in a bare repository.

Comment: @CervEd Thank you for your comment. You're exactly right. The problem was that one. Now it had been fixed but your advices will be useful for similar problems in the future.

Comment: I would rather you not remove this question as I seem to be having similar issues...